# Select query mysql results 'û' appears when I search for 'u'

Tags: mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM enwiki.page where title_text = 'drug';
```

One of the results I got has the tilte_text = 'Drûg'. How can I prevent that?

Comment: prevent what? Just say  no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the correct collate (eg: `utf8_general`)

```
SELECT * FROM enwiki.page where title_text = 'drug' COLLATE utf8_general;
```

MySQL has a CHARSET that tells how does the DB store the values internally. On the other handthe COLLATION instruct the DB how to search, compare and order the data.

For example, if you use any collation that ends in `_ci` (that stands for case insensitive, and you search like this:

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE name LIKE %Home%;
```

You can receive this back:

- Home
- HOME
- homE
- home

and so on...

Same thing happens with the symbols or accents of the letters (in your case û). You have to use a collation that consider them.

Comment: @Andi, have you had a chance to try it out? Need any more help?

Comment: the query didn't work, and also took 134 sec, I am trying to alter table to change the collation of the specific column, it takes time.

Comment: Don't need to change the collation yet. Try using COLLATE utf8_general;

Comment: I tried: utf8mb4_general_ci as well: said is not valid for CHARSET 'utf8'

Comment: Try this mysql command: SHOW COLLATION LIKE %utf8%

Comment: There are a bunch of utf8_(something) or utf8mb4_(something).

Comment: Is there an utf8_unicode? Try that if yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79964/discussion-between-javierfdezg-and-andi).